# What is wrong with ajax.beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with ASP.Net MVC 5 and C#. I am generating views and controllers from my model structure with VS2015 scaffolding feature.
The controllers and views give my application some basic features for editing, creating and deleting records.
All form views contains this declaration:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

I tried to replace this declaration by:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new AjaxOptions()))
```

I have changed something in Edit action Method. As you can see, i commented some code in order to not redirect (and display an error message for example)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "....")] MyDataObject obj)
    {
     /*   if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }*/
        return View(obj);
    }
```

Of course, i have include Microsoft Jquery Unobtrusive Ajax NuGet pacakges and the 2 JS scripts inclusion in the head.
A have also add this line in web.config:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

I have no JS error but the full page is refreshed. I can see it beaucse i add this kind of tags on my page (on the _layout and inside the form)

```
@DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I think your ajax options are missing that's why you are getting error

Comment: I just want the form reload without the full page. There is no need of options in this case ?

Comment: If you want to reload your page then  why you are using Ajax form

Comment: I said i want to reload the form, not the page. There are other widgets on the page outside the form i do not want to reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reload your form only then you have to define AjaxOptions like below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    Url = "api/Person",
    OnComplete = "personSavedComplete" // Your function name define your form refresh logic into this
}))
```

and make sure to use below script :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: Okay there is no way to do this automatically in fact ? I must work with a web API and write a partial view for the form if i understand ?

Comment: I think this is the efficient way to achieve your requirement.. If you define what is your purpose behind refresh the form. I can suggest you more... Thanks

Comment: The purpose is: The user should make mistake when he fills the forms. Outside the form, i have other controls that i do not want to update (a video which is playing for example)

Comment: Ok then simply use my approach and put proper validation into it.. It will surely helps you

Comment: Please mark and upvote my solution if it helps you.. Thanks